Get ingestion date for Snowflake rows without using default expression
I am using Snowpipe Streaming API to ingest data from Kinesis with minimal latency. The API works as expected, however for the monitoring purposes we would like to know the actual latency for events, this means the delta between creation_timestamp and ingestion_timestamp (the moment when the data actually landed into the table). After set of tests I have found out that Snowpipe Streaming API does not support expression default values:
 "message" : "Snowpipe Streaming does not support columns of type AUTOINCREMENT, IDENTITY, GEO, or columns with a default value or collation."

Therefore I can't just have a column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as a default. What are my options to get the actual ingestion timestamp in this case?

try removing the DEFAULT_DDL_COLLATION from account level by setting it to a blank string ('') and confirm if this resolves the issue. (E.g. alter ACCOUNT set DEFAULT_DDL_COLLATION = '';)
